# My loop isn't working like it should

Tags: python-3.x

I've made a program that is supposed to ask you for a password and check if it meets certain requirements and if it doesn't meet them it will ask you for another password. I tried going about doing this re-asking by a loop with a range set to 3. It kind of works but kind of doesn't. If you get it right the first time it will say "Password is valid." and not ask you again. But if you get it wrong the first time, it will ask again but no matter what you input, it will come up with the same error messages as the first time.

```
minlength = (8)
errors = list()
i = 0
for i in range(3):
    pw = str(input("Insert new password."))
    num = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())
    alpha = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isalpha())
    if len(pw) < minlength:
        errors.append("Not enough characters")
    if alpha < 1:
        errors.append("At least on letter is needed")
    if num < 1:
        errors.append("At least one number is needed")
    if pw.isalnum() == False:
        errors.append("Must be alphanumeric")
    if not errors:
        print("Password is valid")
        break
    else:
        print("Password is invalid")
        for err in errors:
            print(err)
            break
```

I need a way to make it not output the same error messages if you input something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to empty the `errors` list at the beginning of the loop, or have it be a local variable declared inside of the loop, like:

```
for i in range(3):
    errors = list()
    ...
```

As your code is currently written, when there are errors, elements are inserted into this list in the first iteration of the loop, and they remain there indefinitely, even in subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you declare the `errors` array only once (before the loop) and repeatedly add to it. You can fix the problem by correctly scoping the `errors` variable - move the `errors = list()` line inside the `for` loop.